# Making a selection of multiple NA's in different rows und colums of a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, selection, na

I have a Dataframe with 12000 rows and 35 columns with multiple NA's in different rows or columns.

I want to create sort of a ifelse-function to select and change these into a value (like "0" or "9999").

My problem is that `is.na(dataframe)`doesn't seem to work on the whole dataframe, but I'm not really charmed with the making a selection for each seperate column.

Is there a better way?

Comment: `data[is.na(data)] <- 0`, what's wrong with this? Can you post an example or the expected output?

Comment: the NA's are actually NaN's .. Maybe this could be the problem?

Comment: Seems more likely that you have string values, like `"NA"`, instead of `NA`. `NaN` values should be treated in the same way. Here's a small example `data = data.frame(x1 = c(1,2,3,4),
                  x2 = c(1,NA,2,NA),
                  x3 = as.character(c("NaN",2,"NA",4)),
                  x4 = c(NaN, 2,3,NA), stringsAsFactors = F);

data[is.na(data)] <- 0`. Can you make sure your columns are `numeric`? @RLave 's suggestion should work, unless you have string values...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

data <- tibble(a = c(1, NA, 2), b = c(NA,1,2)) # let's create some data
data
# A tibble: 3 x 2
      a     b
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1    NA
2    NA     1
3     2     2

data[is.na(data)] <- 0
data
# A tibble: 3 x 2
      a     b
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     0
2     0     1
3     2     2
```

Or with `NaN`:

```
data <- tibble(a = c(1, NaN, 2), b = c(NaN,1,2))
data
# A tibble: 3 x 2
      a     b
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1   NaN
2   NaN     1
3     2     2

data[is.na(data)] <- 0 # still works the same 
data
# A tibble: 3 x 2
      a     b
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     0
2     0     1
3     2     2
```

If you have `"NA"` as strings:

```
data <- tibble(a = c(1, "NA", 2), b = c("NA",1,2))
data[data=="NA"] <- NA # first fix and bring all to "true" NA
data[is.na(data)] <- 0 # still works the same 
data
# A tibble: 3 x 2
      a     b
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     0
2     0     1
3     2     2
```

Answer (score 1):

A `dplyr` solution:

For `NA` or `NaN`:

```
df <- tibble(a = c(1, NaN, 2), b = c(NA,1,2))

df %>% 
  replace(is.na(.), 0)

# A tibble: 3 x 2
      a     b
  <dbl> <dbl>
1    1.    0.
2    0.    1.
3    2.    2.
```

For `"NA"` or `"NaN"` as strings:

```
df <- tibble(a = c(1, "NaN", 2), b = c("NA",1,2))

df %>% 
    mutate_all(funs(replace(., .=="NaN", 0))) %>% 
    mutate_all(funs(replace(., .=="NA", 0))) %>% 
    mutate_all(funs(as.numeric))

# A tibble: 3 x 2
      a     b
  <dbl> <dbl>
1    1.    0.
2    0.    1.
3    2.    2.
```